# IntelliJ IDEA 2019+ Git "Commit Directory" showing excluded maven target folders

Tags: git, maven, intellij-idea

I use a multi-module maven project.
And for me it is a common practice to click with the right button of the mouse on root module and simply select Git -> Commit Directory... option.

In that scenario, I'm always seeing these target folders and I have to always uncheck them.
There is some configuration to not show these target folders on commit command? I'm also using .gitignore but it is not being useful.

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent files from committing, you should add them to .gitingore. Gitingore, however, affects only unversioned files.

According to the screenshot, files from the `target` folders are already tracked by git, thus adding to .gitingore does not affect them. You need to stop tracking them in git first - this can be done with `git rm --cached` command.

Comment: yeah.. that solves the problem. I've needed to clean up before adding them again to .gitignore thanks!